# How can I fill a drop down list with the result of a linq query dynamically?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, drop-down-menu, fill

I have two drop down list. The secod will change according the selected value in the first one.

This is what i'm trying, but is not working.

```
protected void ddTerritory_SelectedIndexChanged (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NorthwindDataContext bd = new NorthwindDataContext();

    var selectedTerritory =
        (from t in bd.EmployeeTerritories
         where t.TerritoryID == this.ddTerritory.SelectedValue
         select t).ToList();

    for (int i = 0; i < selectedTerritory .Count; i++)
    {
        this.ddTerrSelc.Items.Insert(i,
            new ListItem(territorioSeleccionado[0].ToString(), i.ToString()));
    }
}
```

I see some examples, but all of them were using a DataSet as the data source for the drop down list, and as you can see, I'm using linq to sql, so I think there have to be a way to do this without a dataset

Comment: What is not working? Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't need to insert the result set by hand, you can do this instead:

```
var selectedTerritory =
            (from t in bd.EmployeeTerritories
             where t.TerritoryID == this.ddTerritory.SelectedValue
             select t).ToList();

this.ddTerrSelc.DataTextField = "Name";
this.ddTerrSelc.DataValueField = "ID";
this.ddTerrSelc.ItemsSource = selectedTerritory;
```

Comment: The properties DisplayName, ValueMember and ItemsSource give me an error. The error says that the drop down list doesn't have those methods.

Comment: @Aikanáro, If this is a winforms this `ddTerrSelc` should be of type [`ComboBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.aspx) . But, if this is an ASP.Net and `addTerrSelc` of type [`DropDownList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.aspx) then use the followihng properties instead of these in my answer: `addTerrSel.DataValueField = 'Id', addTerrSel.DataTextField = 'Name'`. Sorry for that, see my edit.